# Why won't (onChange) work for an <input>?

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have a primeng/html website that has a number of components - , , etc.

When I need to trigger a function in the angular ts page, I can do this by putting an (onChange) within the component.

This works for everything except an  component.

This is all I'm trying to do...

```
<input [style]="{'width':'80px'}" pInputText type="number" min="0" max="999" (onChange)="myUpdateFunction($event)">
```

But it never gets into the myUpdateFunction.

Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Comment: as long as I know, onChange is not an event of input, you can use `(change)` instead of `(onChange)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input [style]="{'width':'80px'}" pInputText type="number" min="0" max="999" (change)="myUpdateFunction($event)">
```